# Error setting the domain for a grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, data-visualization

I'm making a group bar graph though d3.js, but received an error that I cannot figure out the cause. I'm still new to d3.js , and is trying to learn the script on my own. Any help from the community will be appreciated.

Error is caused by this segment of the code:

```
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(s_category) { 
    return d3.max(s_category.values, 
        function(d) { 
            return d.count; }); 
    })
]);
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The following is my full code:

https://blockbuilder.org/lydiawawa/9efb5df76c08640316efbef702437db7

On the graph, count should be the y-axis, drug_c is the x-axis and s_category determines the groups of the bar graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data structure, which is just a flat array of objects, your snippet for getting the domain makes little sense.

However, knowing that:

1. This is a grouped bar chart, and...
2. You use `values` further down in the code.

It seems to me that you intended to use a `nest` generator, like this:

```
const nestedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.s_category})
    .entries(data);
```

Here is your code with that change: http://bl.ocks.org/GerardoFurtado/80ba2580f758a64046c3e6f513203cd2/7aa3816ad65ed09bd99eeb29ba80892e19cdcbd0

---

PS: your use of the paddings for the band scales is wrong, as well as the band scale for the colours (it should be ordinal). Also, I removed the legends, you have to fix that piece of code.

Comment: I struggled with converting v3 to v4, the scaleOrdinal was spelled as scale.ordinal in v3 and some post online said it has been converted to scaleBand...Could you suggest some reference for structuring data for d3.js? I find it rather difficult to create the right JSON file for the desired graphs. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: would you be able to review my other related post? I think it should be a simple fix thank you!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55786238/d3js-group-bar-chart-displaying-cross-tab-between-groups