# Grouped bar chart displaying cross tab between groups

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, data-visualization

I'm trying to make a group bar chart that gives the frequency of two group combos. I referred to this site for rollup and nest function reference:
http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/

I'm trying to use my own dataset to create the following effect:
https://bl.ocks.org/bricedev/0d95074b6d83a77dc3ad

My current attempt with my own data, drug1.csv:
https://blockbuilder.org/lydiawawa/9efb5df76c08640316efbef702437db7

In the console, the grouped counts do not seem to generate the right distributions. Something is wrong with my rollup and nest

```
  const nestedData = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d){return d.s_category})
    .key(function(d){return d.drug_cat})
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
    .entries(data);
```

Following is the desired cross tab distribution count of s_category x drug_cat :

```
      1   2   3   4   5   6
  2 367  35   8   1   1   1
  3 223  24   4   4   2   2
  4  29   5   9   1   2   3
  5  37   1   3   3   2  26
```

Static chart:
[image]

In the animated bar graph that I attempted to create, cross tab count should be the y-axis, drug_c is the x-axis and s_category determines the groups of the bar graph. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you use the nest generator you don't have `drug_cat` and `count` as properties anymore: you have `key` and `values` (or `value` for the inner arrays).

Here is your block builder changing the names of those properties: https://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/f4c825a5f8c92e87cc5a81591ba1f7c9

Comment: Could you enlighten me on how to sort the x-axis in numerical order such that it is in 1,2,3,4,5,6 based on my revised code: https://blockbuilder.org/lydiawawa/970146c168b2acdcb3598164bb41c2db  Or do I need to open another post...XD...

Comment: @lydias Here: https://blockbuilder.org/GerardoFurtado/d077fc815895c42f88167830573ee390

Comment: Thank you! That is so simple; I could have never thought of that. I learned so much through the struggles in the past few days.